# Error : 'User' object has no attribute 'get' when trying to access current user in ModelForms for a ModelChoiceField dropdown

Tags: python, django, modelform, modelchoicefield

So below is the `views.py` and I'm trying to load a view with modelform. And within the modelform I need to load `modelchoicefield` depending on the current user logged in and tried the below solution(check `forms.py`.) When I run it, i get

```
Attribute Error :object has no attribute 'get'
```

Help is highly appreciated, there's nothing in stackoverflow.

views.py:

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form=PreDataForm(request.user)

        return render(request, 'mainlist.html',
                      { "form":form,

        })
```

models.py:

```
class PreData(models.Model):

    journalname = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False, null=True, default='')
```

forms.py:

```
class PreDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    journalname = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model=PreData
        fields=['journalname']

    def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PreDataForm, self).__init__(user, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["journalname"].queryset = Journals.objects.filter(journalusername=user)
```

html file:

```
{% extends 'home-base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}

Welcome to Metrics - JSM

{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div  class="col-md-9 col-centered"  >
    <div class="backeffect" >

            {% if data %}

            {% else %}

                <b>Seems you are first time around here, Why not <b>{% include 'modal_first_stage.html' %}</b>  to get started? :)</b>
            {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModelForm` does not take `user`. You should remove it from your `super()` call.

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PreDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["journalname"].queryset = Journals.objects.filter(journalusername=user)
```

A slightly more re-usable version, which will work with the generic create/update views, is:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(PreDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["journalname"].queryset = Journals.objects.filter(journalusername=user)
```

Comment: thanks @alasair, I got it resolved, but i have another problem please take a look at updated `forms.py` code. it was throwing me ` __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`  this error. As I said, I want to populate modelchoicefield with values from database. :)

Comment: You need to specify a queryset for a `ModelChoiceField`. Since you are setting the `queryset` in `__init__`, you can use an empty queryset: `journalname = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Journals.objects.filter.none())`. Note that there's a mismatch between using a `CharField` in the db and a `ModelChoiceField` in the form. Can't you use a `ForeignKey` in the model? If you're still stuck, please ask a new question because this is a separate problem to your original question.

Comment: Ya I was also thinking the same, using the foreign key, eventually it did solved the problem. But I have different problem now I guess using foreign key , Will ask it as a separate question :)

Comment: There's a typo in my last comment, it should be `queryset=Journals.objects.none()`